# LEDs with same current rating but different forward voltages

Tags: led, led-driver

I have scoured the net for a direct answer but people always end up talking resistor because they don't have constant current.

I have a constant current power supply. LEDs are 700 mA and vary between 2.0 - 2.2 forward voltage to 3.2 - 3.4 V<sub>f</sub>.

My question is:

If I run one 2.2 V<sub>f</sub> LED in series with a 3.4 V<sub>f</sub> led and have my power set at 700 mA then I would need to also supply 5.6 volts. Does running the different forward voltage matter? As long as only 700 mA is supplied I believe I could supply 5.6 to infinity volts without causing damage..?.?

Basically the inverse of conventional circuits with constant voltage and unlimited-ish current.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this is fine.  LED's are more current than voltage sensitive (a switching current controller prevents thermal runaway without dissipating a large amount of power through an inline resistor) and placing elements in series ensures that the same current runs through them, as there is nowhere else for the current to go.  As long as you don't exceed the current rating for a significant period of time and cooling is adequate, the LEDs won't be damaged by rated current.

Your current controller will provide whatever voltage is necessary to the load to cause the set current to flow, within it's limits.  If it is a buck(step down) only controller, it can only provide voltage up to it's input voltage, and if it's a boost(step up) converter, it will provide the necessary output voltage up to the point where its input current hits max, so there will be a minimum input voltage that must be provided for a given load.  Paralleling LEDs with different Vf however requires individual control of each LED.

As far as a resistor goes, think of it as a cheap high-safety, poor quality current controller.  Use them when input voltage is relatively steady and load current is very small compared to available power.  Switching controllers at higher current levels, for variable source voltage, or for variable control of the LEDs.

Comment: Ok thanks for re affirming this. So if i am using a buck controller what would happen if i had the above scenario but with 2 parralel line off the same controller? I believed i just had to maintian 5.6volts but up the amperage to 1.4amps..?

Comment: @Jon If this answer satisfies your question mark it as the accepted answer by clicking the button to the left of it.  If you appreciated it but it doesn't fully answer, then just upvote(if you believe it has merit) and adjust your question so the next person to try knows where this answer was lacking.

Comment: CC's use any series connections where the load voltage is within limits  but adding shunt connections must be matched voltage or W/A to share the same CC supply.  The amount of mismatch in the 5.6V string vs xxx mA results in mismatched sharing by its incremental series resistance and threshold voltage

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist Thanks.  Good point.  In more layman's terms for OP, if part of the series string is parallel, both parallel legs (Shunt and main path) must be voltage balanced with each other so each receives the correct current.  If thermals are an issue this may also necessitate a series resistor on each parallel path to prevent thermal runaway.

Comment: Awsome. This is what i was looking for!

Comment: +1 so really if i run parralell balanced circuits I should be able to run resistors to guarranty no more then 700ma to each branch without introducing inefficiency?

Comment: @Jon Typing +1 doesn't do anything.  Click the gray arrow pointing upwards to upvote things.  If I were you I would try to stick to a completely series arrangement unless you need to control the LEDs individually.  Using resistors at all will decrease efficiency, but it is sometimes necessary.  If you have 700mA LEDs and a 700mA driver, the LEDs must all be in series.  If you had, for example, a 700mA driver and 350 mA LEDs,  You can use two equal strings of 350mA LEDs in parallel, but they must have matched voltage at that current and you may *need* to add a resistor to each string.

Comment: Ok. Haha +1 ment o e more thing! Ok this has sorted everythin out for me thank you. I am using a buck and a cheapo power supply as an experiment! Thanks so much for your input

Comment: "As far as a resistor goes, think of it as a cheap high-safety, poor quality current controller. "  Not always true if used correctly.  CV with resistors can be highly efficient and very stable. i.e. high quality.

Comment: A buck CC driver will most often have a low end on the Vf as well. And there is an overhead on the input so max Vf is usually slightly below input voltage.  Efficiency often suffers with low Vf.

Answer (score 0):

A buck LED driver will have a very specific voltage range.  With a max and min V<sub>f</sub>.  LED CC drivers are sold by their wattage and max voltage.

For example this is a Mean Well 120 Watt driver available in various voltages. Each voltage model has a range of V<sub>f</sub> supported.

[image]

None of which will work for you becasue your V<sub>f</sub> is too low.  The 12V min is 6V.

A higher V<sub>f</sub> is usually more efficient.  It also helps to use a V<sub>in</sub> not too far over the V<sub>f</sub>.

What would be your V<sub>f</sub> if you wired all the LEDs in series?

I limit the string voltages to less than 48V.  typicality 16 in series for white, blue and green, and 21 in series for red, orange, and yellow.

I NEVER power two parallel multiple LED strings with a CC driver. I have tried many times with various string and never did the current balance between the two strings. Closest was a 45/55 split.

> I am using a buck and a cheapo power supply

When all the LEDs have the same V<sub>f</sub> and the desired current is constant, a CV supply and resistors can be an excellent solution.  With the correct constant voltage you can get better than 98% efficiency from the resistors. It depends upon how closely you need the radiance or irradiance of each LED to match.  Even with the same current flowing there will be a variance in output intensity between each LED.

[image]

This would probably work better if you had 8 sets of 5.6V pairs all wired in series for a total string V<sub>f</sub> of 44.8.  You then use a 48V CV supply and a 4.3 Ω 4W resistor for a minimum efficiency of 94%.   With a good CV source you can adjust the output voltage and resistor value for even better efficiency.

If you were to use a 5.7 V CV source and 5.6 V<sub>f</sub>.  This would require measuring the V<sub>f</sub> of the LEDs at 700 mA after they reach thermal equilibrium to calculate the resistor. And use quality LEDs from a manufacturer that specifies the min and max V<sub>f</sub> where the range is not too large.

Running all LEDs in a single string with a singe CC source, is generally the best way to go when you want the same brightness from each LED.

In some projects I use an inexpensive 48V CC driver made with a TI LM3414HV tweaked to 97% efficiency (switching freq. and inductance) powered with a stable high efficiency CV source like a Mean Well HEP at 96% efficiency. Each driver powers a sting of 16 white or blue or 21 red for horticulture projects.  I need current adjustment as the plants grow so resistors will not work well in most projects.